# Properties Editor causes too many unimportant logs in .log file

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, properties-file

In Eclipse based IDE like STS ,JBoss Developer Studio and so on. I install a plugin named `Properties Editor` [jp.gr.java_conf.ussiy.app.propedit_6.0.3.zip](https://zh.osdn.net/projects/propedit/releases/59939)
it brings features for handling *.properties files ,but everytime i create a new file or the workspace /project refreshed, this plugin will log too many messages in metafolder/.log

```
!ENTRY jp.gr.java_conf.ussiy.app.propedit 1 0 2017-08-03 10:10:39.687
!MESSAGE loading file 'application.properties'

!ENTRY jp.gr.java_conf.ussiy.app.propedit 1 0 2017-08-03 10:10:39.695
!MESSAGE loading file 'application.properties'

!ENTRY jp.gr.java_conf.ussiy.app.propedit 1 0 2017-08-03 10:10:39.705
!MESSAGE loading file 'maven-wrapper.properties'

!ENTRY jp.gr.java_conf.ussiy.app.propedit 1 0 2017-08-03 10:10:39.713
!MESSAGE loading file 'application.properties'

!ENTRY jp.gr.java_conf.ussiy.app.propedit 1 0 2017-08-03 10:10:39.721
!MESSAGE loading file 'pom.properties'

!ENTRY jp.gr.java_conf.ussiy.app.propedit 1 0 2017-08-03 10:10:39.728
!MESSAGE loading file 'application.properties'

!ENTRY jp.gr.java_conf.ussiy.app.propedit 1 0 2017-08-03 10:10:39.736
!MESSAGE loading file 'maven-wrapper.properties'
```

I think these messages are too unimportant and these is no need to log these .I want to know how to avoid the plugin logging?

Answer (score 0):

Contact the author. There's no global solution.

Comment: I wrote an email to the author  but no response.so I want to find whether there is solution to eclipse ide log policy